# How to upgrade Zimbra 8.5

Tags: email, updates, zimbra

I am using zimbra 8.02, need to update to 8.5 without losing my mail box and other setups.

Could you guys please help me out and provide me some steps

Answer (score 0):

What Operating system are you using?
You can follow this instructions if you are using Ubuntu -
http://www.jorgedelacruz.es/2014/08/27/zimbra-upgrade-zcs-8-0-7-a-zcs-8-5-0-sobre-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

And then 
https://www.jorgedelacruz.es/2014/08/27/zimbra-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-a-ubuntu-14-04-y-update-de-zcs-8-5-0/

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ZCA 8.0.2 OR ZCS 8.0.2?

If ZCS 8.0.2, This can be upgraded directly to (the latest release at the time) ZCS 8.6.0.

(1) wget the correct version you require from here http://www.zimbra.com/downloads/ to your server in question

(2) untar -xvf zcs-***

(3) run the ./install.sh